# Decomposing an orthogonal matrix as a rotation and reflection in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

Suppose that $X\in O(4)$ and that $\det(X)=-1$. Let $F$ denote the reflection map $(w,x,y,z)\mapsto (w,x,y,-z)$.

I've read that we can write $X=Y\circ F$ for some $Y\in SO(4)$.

However, I can't see why exactly. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Hint: The determinant is multiplicative, and the reflection map is its own inverse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F\circ F=I$, the identity, so $Y=X\circ F$ iff $X=Y\circ F$.
But $\det(X)=\det(Y\circ F)=\det(Y)\det(F)=(-1)(-1)=1$, so $X\in SO(4)$.

Comment: I made a typo in my original post. I meant for some $Y\in SO(4)$. I changed it.

Comment: Never mind, your answer still works.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $G$ is a group, $S$ a subgroup of index$~2$, then $S$ is always a normal subgroup, with two cosets (left and right) $C_0=S$ and $C_1=G\setminus S$. If one picks any $r\in C_1$, then  (left or right) multiplication by $r$ will interchange the cosets $C_0$ and $C_1$ (this is just saying that the quotient $G/S$, having just two elements, necessarily is a cyclic group of order$~2$). Multiplication by a fixed element always being a bijection, this means that every $x\in C_1$ equals $y\cdot r$ for a unique $y$, with $y\in C_0=S$.

Apply this with $G=O(4)$, $S=SO(4)$, and $r=F$ (the hypothesis $\det(X)=-1$ gives you $X\in C_1$).